# escaping @ symbol in email address with php, curl and postfields

Tags: php, curl

I have a call that uses curlopt_postfields to connect to an API server.  I am using php 5.5.  Even though the '@' sign is within the email address, it hangs up the curl request.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    if( !empty( $this->_request->body_params ) )
    {
        if (is_array($this->_request->body_params)) {
            $this->_request->body_data = $this->getParamsWithChecksum($this->_request->body_params);
        } else {
            $this->_request->body_data = $this->_request->body_params;
        }

        // error_log(print_r($this->_request->body_data, 1));
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->_request->body_data);
    }
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
```

Here is the content that makes curl hang forever:

```
{"email":"me@my_host.com","password":"my_password"}
```

strangely, even if I encode the '@' sign, it still breaks

```
{"email":"me%40my_host.com","password":"my_password"}
```

however, if I don't have any '@' sign, encoded or not, it works:

```
{"email":"me at my_host.com","password":"my_password"}
```

This JSON is then converted to an array and encoded via http_build_query inside the getParamsWithChecksum function